# Are there packages/functions in R to convert colors using ICC color profiles?

Tags: r, colors, color-space, color-management, lab-color-space

For an upcoming project I need to do heavy color space calculations, involving conversions to and from Munsell, Lab, RGB and CMYK. Having working with R a lot (albeit in different contexts) I would like to use this to do the heavy lifting. So, I was wondering, if there are any existing functions or packages that provide the possibility to do color space conversions using user-defined **ICC profiles** (say, from sRGB to ISOCoated_v2 or from Lab to AdobeRGB).

I already did some research and found the packages `grDevices` and `colorspace`. The latter seems pretty powerful, but seems to always use sRGB behind the scenes. Or am I wrong? Am I overlooking a package?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, why this has been put on hold as "off topic"? I am not asking for a recommendation. I would simply like to ask for help implementing a color conversion utilizing a possibly existing function or package in R, without anybody suggesting I should implement it myself. How should I word a question like this?

Answer (score 2):

Package **munsell** works entirely in the Munsell colourspace.

```
library(munsell)
cols <- c("5PB 2/4", "5Y 7/8") 
lighter(cols)
# [1] "5PB 3/4" "5Y 8/8"
mnsl2hex("5PB 2/4")
# [1] "#22324C"
```

Package **colorscience** has tools for working with CMYK.

```
library(colorscience)
CMYK2CMY(c(.342, .768, .683, .378))
#             C        M        Y
# [1,] 0.590724 0.855696 0.802826
```

Package **colorspace** does indeed provide a class for the polarLAB colourspace.

```
library(colorspace)
x <- RGB(R = 0.3, G = 0.2, B = 0.4)
x
#        R   G   B
# [1,] 0.3 0.2 0.4
as(x, "polarLAB")
#             L        C        H
# [1,] 55.65476 28.05838 312.0072
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your suggestions regarding munsell and colorscience are very helpful. My problem is more related to color profiles, though. Can you suggest a way (possible using one of these packages) to implement a conversion from, say, sRGB to AdpbeRGB?